# How to change label of diagonal data using a name list

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

I have a diagonal data.

```
Mat <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
colnames(Mat) <- c("A","C","B")
rownames(Mat) <- c("A","C","B")
```

I would like to change the labels using a name list.

```
name <- c("A","B","C")
newname <- c("101","304","403")
namelist<-cbind(name,newname)
```

I would like to get data like below.

```
newMat <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
colnames(newMat) <- c("101","403","304")
rownames(newMat) <- c("101","403","304")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try,

```
namelist<- as.data.frame(namelist)
colnames(Mat) <- namelist$newname[match(colnames(Mat), namelist$name)]
rownames(Mat) <- namelist$newname[match(rownames(Mat), namelist$name)]
Mat

    101 403 304
101   1   4   7
403   2   5   8
304   3   6   9

name <- c("A","B","C")
newname <- c("101","304","403")
namelist<-cbind(name,newname)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I apply your code, row names of Mat have included "X101", "X403", "X304".  Can I exclude this "X"?

Comment: @marie Well, did you use `namelist` with `namelist` above? I didn't get `X` in front of `101`'s....